# How to refresh JWT token using Apollo and GraphQL

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

So we're creating a React-Native app using Apollo and GraphQL. I'm using JWT based authentication(when user logs in both an ***activeToken*** and ***refreshToken*** is created), and want to implement a flow where the token gets refreshed automatically when the server notices it's been expired.

The Apollo Docs for Apollo-Link-Error provides a good [starting point](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error/#retrying-failed-requests) to catch the error from the ApolloClient:

```js
onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    for (let err of graphQLErrors) {
      switch (err.extensions.code) {
        case 'UNAUTHENTICATED':
          // error code is set to UNAUTHENTICATED
          // when AuthenticationError thrown in resolver

          // modify the operation context with a new token
          const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
          operation.setContext({
            headers: {
              ...oldHeaders,
              authorization: getNewToken(),
            },
          });
          // retry the request, returning the new observable
          return forward(operation);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

However, I am really struggling to figure out how to implement **getNewToken()**.
My GraphQL endpoint has the resolver to create new tokens, but I can't call it from Apollo-Link-Error right?

So how do you refresh the token if the Token is created in the GraphQL endpoint that your Apollo Client will connect to?

Comment: The onError link runs after a request. I don't think you can simply forward to try again. Ideally, you can determine if your current token is still valid in the frontend e.g. by looking at the `exp` claim in a JWT. Then you could use this excellent link: https://github.com/newsiberian/apollo-link-token-refresh

Comment: You can call your GraphQL enpoint using `window.fetch`. This is a bit more work but should be no problem for a single query. Simply `POST` to the endpoint with a JSON object containing `query` and optionally `variables` and `operation`.

Answer (score 29):

The [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error/#retrying-failed-requests) given in the the Apollo Error Link documentation is a good starting point but assumes that the `getNewToken()` operation is synchronous.

In your case, you have to hit your GraphQL endpoint to retrieve a new access token. This is an asynchronous operation and you have to use the `fromPromise` utility function from the [apollo-link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link) package to transform your Promise to an Observable.

```js
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
import { fromPromise, ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";

let apolloClient;

const getNewToken = () => {
  return apolloClient.query({ query: GET_TOKEN_QUERY }).then((response) => {
    // extract your accessToken from your response data and return it
    const { accessToken } = response.data;
    return accessToken;
  });
};

const errorLink = onError(
  ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      for (let err of graphQLErrors) {
        switch (err.extensions.code) {
          case "UNAUTHENTICATED":
            return fromPromise(
              getNewToken().catch((error) => {
                // Handle token refresh errors e.g clear stored tokens, redirect to login
                return;
              })
            )
              .filter((value) => Boolean(value))
              .flatMap((accessToken) => {
                const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
                // modify the operation context with a new token
                operation.setContext({
                  headers: {
                    ...oldHeaders,
                    authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                  },
                });

                // retry the request, returning the new observable
                return forward(operation);
              });
        }
      }
    }
  }
);

apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
});

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
    <MyRootComponent />
  </ApolloProvider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApplication', () => App);
```

You can stop at the above implementation which worked correctly until two or more requests failed concurrently. So, to handle concurrent requests failure on token expiration, have a look at [this post](https://able.bio/AnasT/apollo-graphql-async-access-token-refresh--470t1c8).

Comment: How would you then update the cookie with the new token?

Comment: @MustKillBill This workflow is for header-based authentification where the jwt can be accessed, set or stored by the client. In cookie-based authentication, the client cannot access cookies with JavaScript as they are usually marked HTTPOnly. So it's up to the server to send cookies by using the Set-Cookie HTTP header which  instructs the web browser to store the cookie and send it back in future requests to the server.

Answer (score 13):

**Update - Jan 2022**
you can see basic React JWT Authentication Setup from: https://github.com/bilguun-zorigt/React-GraphQL-JWT-Authentication-Example

I've also added the safety points to consider when setting up authentication on both the frontend and backend on the Readme section of the repository. (XSS attack, csrf attack etc...)

**Original answer - Dec 2021**

My solution:

- Works with concurrent requests (by using single promise for all requests)
- Doesn't wait for error to happen
- Used second client for refresh mutation

```js
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

async function getRefreshedAccessTokenPromise() {
  try {
    const { data } = await apolloClientAuth.mutate({ mutation: REFRESH })
    // maybe dispatch result to redux or something
    return data.refreshToken.token
  } catch (error) {
    // logout, show alert or something
    return error
  }
}

let pendingAccessTokenPromise = null

export function getAccessTokenPromise() {
  const authTokenState = reduxStoreMain.getState().authToken
  const currentNumericDate = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)

  if (authTokenState && authTokenState.token && authTokenState.payload &&
    currentNumericDate + 1 * 60 <= authTokenState.payload.exp) {
    //if (currentNumericDate + 3 * 60 >= authTokenState.payload.exp) getRefreshedAccessTokenPromise()
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(authTokenState.token))
  }

  if (!pendingAccessTokenPromise) pendingAccessTokenPromise = getRefreshedAccessTokenPromise().finally(() => pendingAccessTokenPromise = null)

  return pendingAccessTokenPromise
}

export const linkTokenHeader = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenPromise()
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: accessToken ? `JWT ${accessToken}` : '',
    }
  }
})


export const apolloClientMain = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    linkError,
    linkTokenHeader,
    linkMain
  ]),
  cache: inMemoryCache
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the full code you are using for the apollo interface? Ideally with one example, such as login? I cant put my finger exactly how this would work with my existing code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that great example. It looks like you are using https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/index.html which uses a single token for the auth, whereas I am using https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/ which uses a separate refresh token. I added in a refresh token to your code and am trying to get it working. Wish me luck :)

Comment: shouldn't this: `currentNumericDate + 1 * 60` be `(currentNumericDate + 1) * 60` ?

Comment: @Stathis Ntonas 1 * 60 is just adding 1 minute, meaning if token is not going to expire in 1 minute, refreshing is not needed.

Comment: @earthguestg then in this case `currentNumericDate + 60` is enough, no need for `1 * 60`

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: @earthguestg Great solution. How does it take care of concurrent requests? WIll using 1 promise have impact on the ux?

Comment: @Rahul Purohit Apollo itself handles the concurrent requests very well, so it's just using that. The 1 promise is only holding those concurrent requests till new token is resolved. So there's no impact on the ux that I'm aware of.

Comment: Love that this will only get the refresh token once and not a dozen times for a dozen different concurrent or semi-concurrent queries/mutations

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JWT, you should be able to detect when your JWT token is about to expire or if it is already expired.

Therefore, you do not need to make a request that will always fail with 401 unauthorized.

You can simplify the implementation this way:

````js
const REFRESH_TOKEN_LEGROOM = 5 * 60

export function getTokenState(token?: string | null) {
    if (!token) {
        return { valid: false, needRefresh: true }
    }

    const decoded = decode(token)
    if (!decoded) {
        return { valid: false, needRefresh: true }
    } else if (decoded.exp && (timestamp() + REFRESH_TOKEN_LEGROOM) > decoded.exp) {
        return { valid: true, needRefresh: true }
    } else {
        return { valid: true, needRefresh: false }
    }
}


export let apolloClient : ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>

const refreshAuthToken = async () => {
  return apolloClient.mutate({
    mutation: gql```
    query refreshAuthToken {
      refreshAuthToken {
        value
      }```,
  }).then((res) => {
    const newAccessToken = res.data?.refreshAuthToken?.value
    localStorage.setString('accessToken', newAccessToken);
    return newAccessToken
  })
}

const apolloHttpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: Config.graphqlUrl
})

const apolloAuthLink = setContext(async (request, { headers }) => {
  // set token as refreshToken for refreshing token request
  if (request.operationName === 'refreshAuthToken') {
    let refreshToken = localStorage.getString("refreshToken")
    if (refreshToken) {
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}`,
        }
      }
    } else {
      return { headers }
    }
  }

  let token = localStorage.getString("accessToken")
  const tokenState = getTokenState(token)

  if (token && tokenState.needRefresh) {
    const refreshPromise = refreshAuthToken()

    if (tokenState.valid === false) {
      token = await refreshPromise
    }
  }

  if (token) {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    }
  } else {
    return { headers }
  }
})

apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: apolloAuthLink.concat(apolloHttpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
````

The advantage of this implementation:

- If the access token is about to expire (REFRESH_TOKEN_LEGROOM), it will request a refresh token without stopping the current query. Which should be invisible to your user
- If the access token is already expired, it will refresh the token and wait for the response to update it. Much faster than waiting for the error back

The disadvantage:

- If you make many requests at once, it may request several times a refresh. You can easily protect against it by waiting a global promise for example. But you will have to implement a proper race condition check if you want to guaranty only one refresh.

Comment: This is in react native btw, but the logic is the same for web

Answer (score 2):

after checking this topic and some others very good on internet, my code worked with the following solution

```js
import {
  ApolloClient,
  NormalizedCacheObject,
  gql,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import jwt_decode, { JwtPayload } from 'jwt-decode';

import {
  getStorageData,
  setStorageData,
  STORAGE_CONTANTS,
} from '../utils/local';

export function isRefreshNeeded(token?: string | null) {
  if (!token) {
    return { valid: false, needRefresh: true };
  }

  const decoded = jwt_decode<JwtPayload>(token);

  if (!decoded) {
    return { valid: false, needRefresh: true };
  }
  if (decoded.exp && Date.now() >= decoded.exp * 1000) {
    return { valid: false, needRefresh: true };
  }
  return { valid: true, needRefresh: false };
}

export let client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

const refreshAuthToken = async () => {
  const refreshToken = getStorageData(STORAGE_CONTANTS.REFRESHTOKEN);

  const newToken = await client
    .mutate({
      mutation: gql`
        mutation RefreshToken($refreshAccessTokenRefreshToken: String!) {
          refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: $refreshAccessTokenRefreshToken) {
            accessToken
            status
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: { refreshAccessTokenRefreshToken: refreshToken },
    })
    .then(res => {
      const newAccessToken = res.data?.refreshAccessToken?.accessToken;
      setStorageData(STORAGE_CONTANTS.AUTHTOKEN, newAccessToken, true);
      return newAccessToken;
    });

  return newToken;
};

const apolloHttpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
});

const apolloAuthLink = setContext(async (request, { headers }) => {
  if (request.operationName !== 'RefreshToken') {
    let token = getStorageData(STORAGE_CONTANTS.AUTHTOKEN);

    const shouldRefresh = isRefreshNeeded(token);

    if (token && shouldRefresh.needRefresh) {
      const refreshPromise = await refreshAuthToken();

      if (shouldRefresh.valid === false) {
        token = await refreshPromise;
      }
    }

    if (token) {
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: `${token}`,
        },
      };
    }
    return { headers };
  }

  return { headers };
});

client = new ApolloClient({
  link: apolloAuthLink.concat(apolloHttpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution is using RetryLink. [retryIf supports async operations](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/433) so one could do something like this:

```js
class GraphQLClient {
  constructor() {
    const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: '<graphql-endpoint>', fetch: fetch })
    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => this._getAuthHeaders(headers))
    const retryLink = new RetryLink({
      delay: { initial: 300, max: Infinity, jitter: false },
      attempts: {
        max: 3,
        retryIf: (error, operation) => this._handleRetry(error, operation)
    }})
    
    this.client = new ApolloClient({
      link: ApolloLink.from([ authLink, retryLink, httpLink ]),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    })
  }

  async _handleRetry(error, operation) {
    let requiresRetry = false
          
    if (error.statusCode === 401) {
        requiresRetry = true
        if (!this.refreshingToken) {
          this.refreshingToken = true
          await this.requestNewAccessToken()
          operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => this._getAuthHeaders(headers))
          this.refreshingToken = false
        }
    }

    return requiresRetry
  }

  async requestNewAccessToken() {
    // get new access token
  }

  _getAuthHeaders(headers) {
    // return headers 
  }
}
```