# Apollo GraphQL React refresh token(with AWS amplify) fromPromise --> flatMap() is not being triggered at all

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, apollo-client

So I followed the documentation from this post to implement the refresh token logic [How to refresh JWT token using Apollo and GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327448/how-to-refresh-jwt-token-using-apollo-and-graphql)

Here's my code:

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
const getNewToken = () => {
  return Auth.currentSession()
    .then(data => {
      return {
        accessToken: data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
        refreshToken: data.getRefreshToken().getToken()
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```

```
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  stateLink,
  authLink,
  onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path, extensions }) => {
        if (message.includes('Access Token has expired')) {
          console.log('access token has expired');
          return fromPromise(
            getNewToken().catch(error => {
              console.log('error', error)
              // Handle token refresh errors e.g clear stored tokens, redirect to login
            })
          )
            .filter(value => Boolean(value))
            .flatMap(accessToken => {
              console.log('access token!!!', accessToken)
              const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
              // modify the operation context with a new token
              operation.setContext({
                headers: {
                  ...oldHeaders,
                  authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                }
              });
              // retry the request, returning the new observable
              return forward(operation);
            });
        }
        console.log(
          `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
        );
      });
    }
    if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
  }),
  linkHttp
]);
```

But it does not work, the request is not made again and even the `console.log('access token!!!', accessToken)` is not being called.I don't know why the code inside flatMap() is not being executed. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong, please advise what should I do

Comment: Hey, did you eventually find a solution?