# How to refresh a token asynchronously using Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I use postMessage to get the token from the mobile client. Js client sends request using `requestRefresh` function with postMessage to receive JWT token. Mobile clients execute JS code using a method call, which is described inside the WebView. I save the token in a cookie when I receive it in webview. I successfully get a token the first time I render a component, but I have a problem with updating the token asynchronously in the Apollo client when an "Unauthenticated" or "Invalid jwt token" error occurs.

I don't understand how I can call the call and response function from the mobile client asynchronously inside the onError handler and save the token.

I've reviewed several resources on this, StackOverflow answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327448/how-to-refresh-jwt-token-using-apollo-and-graphql), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965347/how-to-execute-an-async-fetch-request-and-then-retry-last-failed-request/51321068#51321068), Github examples [3](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-error#retrying-failed-requests), [4](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/646), and this blog post [5](https://able.bio/AnasT/apollo-graphql-async-access-token-refresh--470t1c8), but didn't find similar case
.

**index.tsx**

```
import React, { Suspense, useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink, ApolloProvider, from } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { App } from 'app';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: process.env.API_HOST,
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = cookies.get('token');

    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        },
    };
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors)
        for (const err of graphQLErrors) {
            switch (err?.extensions?.code) {
                case 'UNAUTHENTICATED':
                  // error code is set to UNAUTHENTICATED


           //How to call and process a response from a mobile client here?
    
    
            const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
            operation.setContext({
              headers: {
                ...oldHeaders,
                authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
              },
            });
            // retry the request, returning the new observable
            return forward(operation);
            }
        }
});


const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        typePolicies: {
            User: {
                keyFields: ['userId'],
            },
        },
    }),
    link: from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
    uri: process.env.API_HOST,
    connectToDevTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});


import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

interface IMessage {
    action: string;
    data?: {
        text: string;
        old_jwt?: string;
    };
}

enum Actions {
    refreshJWT = 'refresh_jwt',
}

interface IMessageEventData {
    action: Actions;
    success: boolean;
    payload: {
        data: string;
    };
}

export const Index: React.FC = () => {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const token = cookies.get('token');

    const message = useMemo((): IMessage => {
        return {
            action: Actions.refreshJWT,
            data: {
                text: 'Hello from JS',
                ...(token && { old_jwt: token }),
            },
        };
    }, [token]);

    const requestRefresh = useCallback(() => {
        if (typeof Android !== 'undefined') {
            Android.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
        } else {
            window?.webkit?.messageHandlers.iosHandler.postMessage(message);
        }
    }, [message]);

    // @ts-ignore
    window.callWebView = useCallback(
        ({ success, payload, action }: IMessageEventData) => {
            if (success) {
                if (action === Actions.refreshJWT) {
                    cookies.set('token', payload.data, { path: '/' });
                }
            } else {
                throw new Error(payload.data);
            }
        },
        [requestRefresh]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        requestRefresh();
    }, []);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                 <App />
            </ApolloProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code finally solved my problem

```
import { fromPromise } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';

interface IMessage {
    action: string;
    data?: {
        text?: string;
        old_jwt?: string;
    };
}

interface IMessageEventData {
    action: Actions;
    success: boolean;
    payload: {
        data: string;
    };
}

enum Actions {
    refreshJWT = 'refresh_jwt',
}

let authToken = '';
let time: NodeJS.Timeout;
let countOfRequests = 0;
let isRefreshing = false;

const INTERVAL_BETWEEN_REQUESTS = 30000;
const MAX_COUNT_REQUESTS = 2;

let pendingRequests = [];

const resolvePendingRequests = () => {
    pendingRequests.map((callback) => callback());
    pendingRequests = [];
};


const message = (): IMessage => {
    return {
        action: Actions.refreshJWT,
        data: {
            ...(authToken && { old_jwt: authToken }),
        },
    };
};

const asyncRequestRefresh = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        if (typeof Android !== 'undefined') {
            // @ts-ignore
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            Android.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message()));
        } else {
            // @ts-ignore
            window?.webkit?.messageHandlers.inDriveriOSHandler.postMessage(message());
        }
        resolve('ok');
    });
};

const getNewToken = async () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        window.callWebView = ({ success, payload, action }: IMessageEventData) => {
            if (success) {
                if (action === Actions.refreshJWT) {
                    authToken = payload.data;
                    resolve(payload.data);
                }
            } else {
                reject(payload.data);
            }
        };
    });

export const getToken = async () => {
    countOfRequests++;

    time = setTimeout(() => {
        if (countOfRequests > MAX_COUNT_REQUESTS) {
            clearTimeout(time);
        } else {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
            getToken();
        }
    }, INTERVAL_BETWEEN_REQUESTS);

    return asyncRequestRefresh()
        .then(getNewToken)
        .then((token) => {
            clearTimeout(time);
            return token;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};

export const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: authToken ? `Bearer ${authToken}` : '',
        },
    };
});

export const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
        for (const err of graphQLErrors) {
            switch (err?.extensions?.code) {
                case 'FORBIDDEN':
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-case-declarations
                    let innerForward;

                    if (!isRefreshing) {
                        isRefreshing = true;
                        innerForward = fromPromise(
                            getToken()
                                // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
                                .then((token) => {
                                    resolvePendingRequests();
                                    console.info(`token refreshed: ${token}`);
                                    authToken = token;
                                    operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
                                        headers: {
                                            // Re-add old headers
                                            ...headers,
                                            // Switch out old access token for new one
                                            authorization: `Bearer ${token}` || '',
                                        },
                                    }));
                                })
                                // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.error(error);
                                    pendingRequests = [];
                                })
                                // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
                                .finally(() => {
                                    isRefreshing = false;
                                })
                        );
                    } else {
                        innerForward = fromPromise(
                            // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
                            new Promise((resolve) => {
                                pendingRequests.push(() => resolve());
                            })
                        );
                    }

                    return innerForward.flatMap(() => forward(operation));
            }
        }
    }
    if (networkError) {
        console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }
});
```